# How to share variables between parent and child screens?

Tags: iphone

I have 2 screens - A and B.
A is the parent, initializing the child - B.

I would like screen A to pass some data to screen B (contact ID for that matter). Using global variable which will hold the contact ID to be passed seems like a waste, since the only screens that will use this global variables are A and B, and not the entire application.

In Android one can use: 
    myIntent.putExtra("key", "value");

How can I achieve this in iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a property on class B, e.g

in ClassB.h...

```
@interface ClassB : UIViewController
{
  NSString *contactID;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *contactID;

@end
```

Then put

```
@synthesize contactID
```

In your implementation  for ClassB.

Now you can do

```
ClassB *b = [[ClassB alloc] init];
b.contactID = @"something";
```

Answer (score 1):

Create property in your B view controller, let's say ...

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *contactID;
```

... and assign your contact ID before presenting view controller B in this way ...

```
viewControllerB.contactID = ...desiredContactID...;
```

Comment: Tnx. blaaaahhhhhh damn comments char counter.